# R `update.packages()` deletes some packages

Tags: r, package, updates

It seems that almost every time I run `update.packages()`, most of the packages are updated, but also a few are *removed* and not replaced. This time, I copied the activity trail, and after discovering some packages were missing, it appears that those deleted packages correspond to messages like this:

```
package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘MASS’
```

While the message says the package wasn't deleted, it was. Apparently,  `update.packages()` thinks it wasn't, so it doesn't replace it with the new code that it had downloaded.

Losing a sporadic few packages that I thought I was updating is extremely annoying; so I would like to understand what it is that's going wrong so I can avoid it.

I may have a clue about what happens. I use RStudio for most of my work, but I usually bring up a new RGui session and run `update.packages()` there, so I can keep working while all those updates are being done. Is this likely to be what is causing these deletions? And if so, why?

Comment: Well, "unpacked" doesn't mean removed. Nothing in that message means that MASS has been removed. Messages like that usually come up for me when I have the package actively loaded when i'm trying to update it and it can't be unloaded because it's being used. It's best to update in a fresh session where you have no packages loaded. It's probably that they aren't deleted, but they may become incompatible with the other versions you have install.

Comment: No. I am not imagining this. The package was actually removed. I can see that by looking st the library directory where the folder no longer exists.

Comment: I edited the question in an attempt to clarify.